# JQuery Listener not Listening

Tags: jquery, listener

I am trying to click an input type checkbox.. when clicked an AJAX call is performed.  I have a listener set up but nothing fires ... firebug also shows nothing.

Code:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js{API removed}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
alert('test');
if ($('#profile_visible:checked').val() !== null) {

        $.ajax({
          url: 'inc/profileVisible.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#resultProfileVisible').innerhtml="success";
            alert('Load was performed.');
          }
        });
}
    }
    </script>
```

...and in the body of the document:

```
    <form method="post" action="profile/<?php echo $_SESSION['usern']; ?>/settings">
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="profile_visible" name="profile_visible" /> Show Profile<span id="resultProfileVisible"></span></p>
    </form>
```

thanks

Comment: Which listener are you referring to? I can only see one - the document ready. Is that the one you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an event listener set up. Bind event handlers with `on` (jQuery > 1.7) or `bind` (jQuery < 1.7) or jQuery's various shortcut methods (like `.change` or `.click`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#profile_visible").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'inc/profileVisible.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#resultProfileVisible').html("success");
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Also, use `.html()` instead of `.innerHtml` to set an element's html contents when using a jQuery object.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/8x6h8/1/

Answer (score 1):

The only listener is the DOM ready, so it will only run once.

You have a few issues with your code. See below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('test');
           // I assume you just want to see if it is checked
    if ($('#profile_visible').is(':checked')) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/profileVisible.php',
            success: function (data) {
                  // jQuery has .html(), not innerhtml
                $('#resultProfileVisible').html( "success" );
                alert('Load was performed.');
            }
        });
    }
}) // <-- was missing closing parentheses
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  much appreciated... I have been on a jQuery 4 year hiatus and just trying to get back into it. naturally your advice helped.. now I get the alert "test" to show on page load.  however when I check the checkbox the $ajax doesn't fire.  the path to the PHP script is correct.    Firebug tells me under the "Script" that: Access to restricted URI denied.  Again, the path to the ajax server side script is correct.  advice? thanks

Comment: @user1175528: Not sure of your directory structure, but maybe you need an absolute path? `'/inc/profileVisible.php'`. And if you need it to run on every click, see [Andrew Whitaker's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9047445/1106925).

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#profile_visible').change(function(){ // handler when the checkbox is toggled
   if($(this).attr('checked')) { // check if it is checked
        $.ajax({
          url: 'inc/profileVisible.php',
          success: function(data) {
            $('#resultProfileVisible').html("success"); // change here
            alert('Load was performed.');
          }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `if($(this).attr('checked')` => `if(this.checked)`

Comment: yeah you are right man.. 1st one is jquery and the other is pure javascript... any one of them can be used.

Comment: thank you very much, I implemented this code and it works beautifully.  I see my mistake(s).. much appreciated.

Comment: As a modification, I have 3 separate input type=checkboxes, therefore I am writing 3 different functions, one for each checkbox.  Problem is, the second and third don't work when clicked... I think it has to do with if($(this).attr(click)... I suspect it's the "this" that is messing stuff up.  Is there an easier way to write the code?

Comment: you can include checkbox ids separated by commas like "#profile_visible,#profile_visible_1". is it that you are including '<p><input type="checkbox" id="profile_visible" name="profile_visible" /> Show Profile<span id="resultProfileVisible"></span></p>'
 multiple times ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing your listener. Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#profile_visible').change(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'inc/profileVisible.php',
                success: function(data) {
                $('#resultProfileVisible').html("success"); // change here
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `if($(this).attr('checked')` => `if(this.checked)`